# Jhipster - check Role of a User

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jhipster, roles

I have the following method in UserResourse.java generated by default by Jhipster:

```
@DeleteMapping("/users/{login:" + Constants.LOGIN_REGEX + "}")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole(\"" + AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN + "\")")
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteUser(@PathVariable String login) {
    log.debug("REST request to delete User: {}", login);

    userService.deleteUser(login);
    return ResponseEntity.noContent().headers(HeaderUtil.createAlert(applicationName,  "userManagement.deleted", login)).build();
}
```

If the user to be deleted has a certain role I want to make other changes to the database. I need to write something like :

```
Optional<User> user =  this.userService.findOneByLogin(login);
if(user.get().hasRole("ROLE_USER"){
 // do something
}
```

The User class has an attribute `Set<Authority> authorities` and I am thinking that I can maybe use this to check the role of the user, but I cannot figure out how to do it. Can someone assist me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in many ways, I would delegate this behaviour to the service instead of the resource.

One approach is to add a new method to your `User.java` class that checks whether the user has certain role. Something like:

```java
public boolean hasRole(String role) {
    return this.authorities.stream().map(Authority::getName).anyMatch(a -> a.equals(role));
}
```

And then call it from your `UserService.java`:

```java
public void deleteUser(String login) {
    userRepository.findOneWithAuthoritiesByLogin(login).ifPresent(user -> {

        if (user.hasRole(AuthoritiesConstants.USER)){
            // Do your things here

        }

        userRepository.delete(user);
        log.debug("Deleted User: {}", user);
    });
}
```

Comment: This code could be also moved to a permission evaluator, see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression